# What is the right way to line up a picture to the left of 2 rows of text inside an html table without overflow or cutoff?

Tags: html, css, image, rows

I have a webpage and i have data inside an html table cell (a google orgChart api table cell to be exact).  I want to show an image on the left and then to the right of it show 2 rows of text.  The image is the same height as 2 text rows but it doesn't seem to line up.

If I choose to have the image

```
float:left
```

that aligns everything correctly but then the text overflows beyond the horizontal width of the outer cell.  I am now trying to use both float:left to get the correct alignment but also have the outer td expand to support the full width of the image and text (see code below)

As worse case scenario, i can put it inside its own table where the image is in a td with rowSpan=2 but i was trying to come up with a non table solution (given the other layout is already a table so want to avoid nested tables as that always has performance issues, etc.

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="teamBlock">
    <br><img width="35" src="myimage.png" class="headImage">
    <span class="boldText">My team</span><br/>
    My Level
 </div>
```

and here is the css:

```
.boldText {
    font-weight: bold;
 }

 .headImage 
 {
  text-align: left;
 }

 .teamBlock 
 {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 }
```

Comment: Add your code to better understand your question!!

Comment: Or create a Fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @AT-UID - I have updated my question in terms of description as well as included html and css

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by putting the image and lines of text in divs. For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="pic">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div id="row1"></div>
    <div id="row2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pic, #row1, #row2 {
    float: left;
}

#container {
    width: 200px; /* width of #pic + #row1/row2 */
}

#pic {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#row1, #row2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FnvJj/1/)

Comment: Could you add `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden` to the row? Or any other [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) values?

Comment: i tried that which worked but now the text on the right is overflowing outside the table cell

Comment: @JSW1189 - to be clear, i would want the cell to grow to the size of the text

Comment: not quite, i would still want the red box to be below the blue box but since the whole thing is inside a html table cell, i want the table cell to grow to fit the content

Comment: Do you want it to grow horizontally or vertically? (Vertical example: http://jsfiddle.net/FnvJj/3/). And do you want the image size to grow with it?

Comment: the image width is fixed.  I want it to grow horizontally due to the text (its only one word of text but its a long word )

Comment: You could expand the width of #container, and then remove the fixed width on #row1 and #row2. See http://jsfiddle.net/FnvJj/4/

Comment: see my updated question . . i also added my code in for help.  Ideally i don't want to hard code a fixed width on the container.  I wanted it to grow with the content

Answer (score 0):

you could use divs and style them with margins ect. to get the exact layout you want. A basic example would be:

```
<div style="width:400px; height:200px;">
<img src="../Images/icon-left-panel-compage.png" width="200px" height="200px" style="float:left" />
<div style="width:200px; overflow:auto;">hello my name is brian johnson</div>
<div style="width:200px; overflow:auto;">helloe my name is john brianson</div>
</div>
```

and then apply whatever top margin you want to the second div

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want??? 
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/APgW6/1/)

```
<div class="main">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>
```